# Application crash on UITableview Section deletion

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have implemented an expandable and collapsable UITableView in my iPad application. User may add or delete a section. I am deleting section on the base of button tag that is placed on section header. if I delete section from last to first then it is good otherwise application crashes on 2nd or 3rd delete.  Because when I delete any section then it is not refreshing UIButton's tags.
here is my code

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    /*
     Create the section header views lazily.
     */
    // delete button.
    delButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    delButton.frame = CGRectMake(600.0, 5.0, 35.0, 35.0);
    [delButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    delButton.tag = section;
    [delButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteSectionHeader:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    Section *aSection=[sectionArray objectAtIndex:section];
    if (!aSection.sectionHeaderView) {
        aSection.sectionHeaderView = [[SectionHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, subActivityTableView.bounds.size.width, HEADER_HEIGHT) title:aSection.sectionHeader section:section delegate:self];
        [aSection.sectionHeaderView addSubview:delButton];
    }

    return aSection.sectionHeaderView;
}
-(void)deleteSectionHeader:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSInteger section = sender.tag;
    [sectionArray removeObjectAtIndex:section];
    [subActivityTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    // reload sections to get the new titles and tags
    NSInteger sectionCount = [sectionArray count];
    NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, sectionCount)];
    [subActivityTableView reloadSections:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[subActivityTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: at which line did your code break?

Comment: how does your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` look like ?

Comment: Infect when i delete the last section then it is good but if i delete from the top or middle then on 2nd delete it crashes, because i am using Button tag for section index. and when i delete any section then it is not refreshing the tags of button.